# get group id by group name (Python, Unix)

Tags: python, linux, unix

I want to use Python to get the group id to a corresponding group name.
The routine must work for Unix-like OS (Linux and Mac OS X).

This is what I found so far

```
>>> import grp
>>> for g in grp.getgrall():
...     if g[0] == 'wurzel':
...         print g[2]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you read the [grp module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/grp.html) you'll see that grp.getgrnam(groupname) will return one entry from the group database, which is a tuple-like object. You can either access the information by index or by attribute:

```
>>> import grp
>>> groupinfo = grp.getgrnam('root')
>>> print groupinfo[2]
0
>>> print groupinfo.gr_gid
0
```

Other entries are the name, the encrypted password (usually empty, if using a shadow file, it'll be a dummy value) and all group member names. This works fine on any Unix system, including my Mac OS X laptop:

```
>>> import grp
>>> admin = grp.getgrnam('admin')
>>> admin
('admin', '*', 80, ['root', 'admin', 'mj'])
>>> admin.gr_name
'admin'
>>> admin.gr_gid
80
>>> admin.gr_mem
['root', 'admin', 'mj']
```

The module also offers a method to get entries by gid, and as you discovered, a method to loop over all entries in the database:

```
>>> grp.getgrgid(80)
('admin', '*', 80, ['root', 'admin', 'mj'])
>>> len(grp.getgrall())
73
```

Last but not least, python offers similar functionality to get information on the password and shadow files, in the [pwd](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html) and [spwd](http://docs.python.org/library/spwd.html) modules, which have a similar API.

Comment: Note that because there is a limit to how many members a Unix group can have, some (large) systems have multiple Unix groups with the same GID but different name, for example: `admin`, `admin2`, `admin3`, etc.

You might not be aware of this because files are stored with their numeric UID/GID, and tools like `ls` look up the GID and display the first name encountered, which in my example would be `admin`.

So you may be surprised to find a given user account is not in the `admin` group, but actually the `admin2` or other alias.

You must to filter all groups by GID to find aliases AFAICT.

Answer (score 5):

See [`grp.getgrnam(name)`](http://docs.python.org/library/grp.html#grp.getgrnam):

> `grp.getgrnam(name)`
>
> Return the group database entry for the given group name. KeyError is raised if the entry asked for cannot be found.
>
> Group database entries are reported as a tuple-like object, whose attributes correspond to the members of the group structure:

```
Index   Attribute   Meaning

0   gr_name     the name of the group
1   gr_passwd   the (encrypted) group password; often empty
2   gr_gid  the numerical group ID
3   gr_mem  all the group member’s user names
```

The numerical group ID is at index 2, or 2nd from last, or the attribute `gr_gid`.

GID of `root` is 0:

```
>>> grp.getgrnam('root')
('root', 'x', 0, ['root'])
>>> grp.getgrnam('root')[-2]
0
>>> grp.getgrnam('root').gr_gid
0
>>>
```

Comment: Right. Maybe you could scroll to the top of the doc in your browser.

Answer (score -2):

Using perl:

```
$grp_id = getgrnam($ARGV[0]);
print $grp_id."\n";
```

Comment: Add more info on why this is an answer.